# Trouble deciding return type of a method that returns a SortedSet

Tags: java, naming

I am supposed to make a class that should be a container for an interval of values (like in mathematics). I have already decided that I'll use internally a `SortedSet`.

One of the the things I'm supposed to implement is a method that "gets an ordered set with all the elements in the interval".

```
class Interval {
    private SortedSet sortedSet = new something();

    ...

    <<method that should return an ordered set of values>>
}
```

My question resides in what should be both the method's return type and name. Several hypothesis arise:

1. `SortedSet getSortedElements();` I am internally using a `SortedSet`, so I should return that type. I should state that intent in the method's name.
2. `SortedSet getElements();` I am internally using a `SortedSet`, but there's no point in stating that in the method name(I don't see a big point in this one).
3. `Set getElements();` I should try to always return the most basic type, thus I am returning a Set. By the contract and definition of the method, people already know all the elements are in order.
4. `Set getSortedElements();` For the method return type, the same as above. About the method name, you are stating clearly what this method is going to return: a set of elements that are sorted.

I'm inclined to use `4.` , but the others also seem alright. Is there a clear winner? Why?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  SortedSet already implements what you need with `public SortedSet<E> subSet(E fromElement, E toElement)`

Comment: Re. the name of the method, "Elements" is too generic. the method name should be more descriptive then "<blah>Elements"... especially if one day you need to add another collection to the class, then getElements becomes ambiguous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SortedSet` is an interface with the contract that the elements are sorted. It also exposes some methods not available in `Set` (such as `first()`). If you are supposed to return an object that obeys that contract (for example, returns ordered values on iterator()), then you should return a `Sorted Set`. If not, you should return a `Set` (or a `Collection`).

You figure out what to return based on how you want the result to be used. Think what "gets an ordered set with all the elements in the interval" means first, then worry about the implementation.

By the way the code

```
private SortedSet sortedSet = new SortedSet();
```

is illegal, because `SortedSet` is an interface.  Since this is homework I will leave it to you to figure out why that is a problem.

Comment: +1 The returned value type and parameters type should reflect the contract as much as possible. And by the way, making parameter types less specific and returned type more specific is usually convenient for the caller.

Comment: yes, while you were writing the post I switched to "something" although I'll use a TreeSet.

Answer (score 1):

I think returning a `Set` is the right way to go for maintainability - but I don't like any of the method names.  Why not something more descriptive like :

```
Set getIntervalValues();
```

or something there abouts.

Comment: why is Set more convenient to the caller when the method returns a SortedSet? i would think the opposite: if the caller wants to use the result as a SortedSet she just needs to assign the result to a SortedSet. If she does not care about the order, she can assign the result to a Set. Now, if the method return type is Set, a caller who wants to use it as a SortedSet (e.g. call first() etc') would need to cast it - looks ugly and risky - what if the implementor decides to change the implementation to non-Sorted Set?

Comment: i gave you +1 because i agree with the part about the name of the method

Answer (score 0):

If the method is supposed to return a SortedSet, that should be the return type of the method. Callers can assign the result to a SortedSet or a Set, depending on whether they care about the ordering or not.
if your method javadoc or name imply that you are returning a sorted set but your method return type is only Set, that's like telling your plumber that you will pay him $100 for his services, but then writing in the contract that you will pay him "at least $50".

By returning SortedSet
1) your are promising your clients that you are and will be returning a sorted set. you cannot change that contract (to Set) without breaking your client's code (won't compile).
If instead your method return type is Set, it doesn't matter what you promise your clients/callers in your javadoc or in the name of the method, you can still change the implementation at any time to return a non-sorted set. If the return type is Set and the caller wants the SortedSet capabilities, they can cast the returned value to SortedSet (ugly) but then one day if you decide that you're just going to return a non-sorted (still) Set, your callers code will break at runtime (very risky to your clients. imagine your clients code is running fine and then they upgrade the library that you provided...).
2) the callers may need a sorted set of your result. If you are returning Set, they may be tempted to re-sort your result (would you want to require the to read your javadoc?). If you are returning SortedSet they know they don't need to re-sort.